# Dynamically assigning object keys and values with "for"

Tags: javascript

I have a function, `SWFUpload_config`, which takes an argument, `post_params_arr` - an object.

```
post_params_arr = {"ajaxtask":"swfupload_files", "param": "2012"}
```

I need to parse that `post_params_arr` and dynamically add keys and values to `swfu_settings` in the following way (please notice that swfu_settings has by default 'SWFSESSID' : session_id and all other keys:values must be added from post_params_arr):

```
function SWFUpload_config (post_params_arr) {
    var swfu_settings = {
        'SWFSESSID' : session_id,
        'ajaxtask' : 'swfupload_files',
        'param' : '2012'
    };
}
```

How can I achieve that? How would I parse `post_params_arr` inside `swfu_settings` where I am assigning keys and values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you'd access any other object...

```
var swfu_settings = {
    ajaxtask: post_params_arr.ajaxtask,
    param: post_params_arr.param
};
```

Or do you mean it's JSON? If you have jQuery, parse it using `jQuery.parseJSON`; otherwise, use `JSON.parse` and fall back on `eval('(' + post_params_arr + ')')`.

---

If you need to shallow-clone the object for some reason, a `for in` loop will work:

```
var swfu_settings = {
    SWFSESSID: 'blah'
    // etc.
};

for(var x in post_params_arr) {
    if(post_params_arr.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
        swfu_settings[x] = post_params_arr[x];
    }
}
```

Comment: not only values but also keys must by dynamically taken from argument post_params_arr

Comment: @ihtus: Any reason you can't just use `post_params_arr` instead of `swfu_settings`?

Comment: I have edited the prim post: because swfu_settings has already 'SWFSESSID' : session_id and other keys:values from post_params_arr must be added to swfu_settings